# Cant get Datatable to fill because of "da.Fill(dt);" not working. please help, for an assignment

Tags: c#, syntax-error

here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace SDD_Single_Project___Michael
{


    public partial class AllData : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

        public AllData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\schoolwork\Year 11\SDD\3 SINGLE TASK\SDD Single Project - Michael \SDD Single Project - Michael \bin\Persondata.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
        }

        private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide(); //hides this page
            MainScreen frm = new MainScreen(); //finds the next screen (the main game)
            frm.Show(); //shows it
        }

        private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open(); //opens connection 
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(); //declare our object of oleDB command
                command.Connection =  connection; // the connection is giving to the command
                string query = "select * Persondata";
                command.CommandText = query; // pass the query to the command

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt); // the error supposedly occurs here!!
                dataGridView1.DataSource =  dt;


                connection.Close(); // closes the connection
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

the error code i get when i try running the program is that it is a syntax error at'*Persondata' on line 46 (which is theda.Fill(dt); line) and i cant figure it out. Please help its for an assignment.

Comment: Please post the actual error message

Comment: your query doesn't have the "from" keyword, it should be "select * from Persondata". Also, if I'm correct, you are reading from an MS Access file - try also putting the name of the table into [] ([Persondata]).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is throwing an exception at the moment, and I'm pretty sure that exception is already telling you exactly what is wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
"select * Persondata"
```

must be

```
"select * FROM Persondata"
```